# Mapping Area to Subdomain ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to Map areas I've created to subdomains and failing.

I have an area named "sugar" and I'm using a `SubDomainRouteTransformer` class I found online that worked for an ASP.NET core 5 project with the code:

```
    

    public class SubDomainRouteTransformer : DynamicRouteValueTransformer
    {
        public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
        {
            var subDomain = httpContext.Request.Host.Host.Split(".").First();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(subDomain))
            {
                values["controller"] = subDomain;
            }
            return values;
        }
    }
```

in my program.cs file I implement it thus

```
    builder.Services.TryAddTransient<SubDomainRouteTransformer>();

    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    
    app.MapDynamicControllerRoute<SubDomainRouteTransformer>("Sugar", "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

However, whenever I try accessing the main website, which is the one under the "default" route, I keep getting directed to the "sugar" area. Is there a proper way I can implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,with your codes,"Sugar" would be considered as the route parttern,you have to remove "Sugar"

[image]

Secondly

> whenever I try accessing the main website, which is the one under the
> "default" route, I keep getting directed to the "sugar" area

check if subdomain exists:

```
var host = httpContext.Request.Host.Host;
var subDomain = host.Split(".").Count() > 1 ? host.Split(".").First() : "";
```

If you don't want to be directed to Sugar area when subdomain doesn't exists,try

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subDomain))
{
  values["controller"] = subDomain;
  values["area"] = subDomain;
}
else
{
   values.Remove("area");
 }
```

I tried with a minimal example:

[image]

[image]

in program.cs:

```
app.MapDynamicControllerRoute<SubDomainRouteTransformer>("{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

SubDomainRouteTransformer:

```
public class SubDomainRouteTransformer : DynamicRouteValueTransformer
    {
        public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
        {
            var host = httpContext.Request.Host.Host;
            var subDomain = host.Split(".").Count() > 1 ? host.Split(".").First() : "";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subDomain))
            {
                values["controller"] = subDomain;
                values["area"] = subDomain;
            }
            else
            {
                values.Remove("area");
            }
            return values;
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for this. It actually works! Quick question though, how would I get the redirect working? i.e. from your example, automatically redirect to the subdomain from the area?

Comment: You may need a custom middleware,check the value of area in routevalue dictionary and your subdomain,if don't match, redirect to  subdomain accroding to the area