# ASP.NET Core friendly URL and culture routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-7.0

I have an ASP.NET Core project; I want to make a dynamic url structure in this project.

```
route : 
   endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "seourlparam",
      pattern: "{culture}/{seourl}",
      defaults: new { culture = "tr-TR", controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
  );
```

Base controller:

```
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync( ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    string seourl = context.RouteData.Values["seourl"] + "";
    string controllername = context.RouteData.Values["controller"] + "";
    string actionname = context.RouteData.Values["action"] + "";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(seourl) && controllername == "Home" && actionname == "Index")
    {
        var Sayfa = dbContext.Sayfas.FirstOrDefault(x => x.URL == seourl);

        if (Sayfa != null)
        {
            context.RouteData.Values["controller"] = Sayfa.ControllerName;
            context.RouteData.Values["action"] = Sayfa.ActionName;
        }
    }

    await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
}
```

My problem is when I click on the link, for example, Controller: Page Action: Page Detail, but the view part is correct, but it sees the `HomeController Index` as the controller.

Thank you if you can help

Comment: Seems you overrided OnActionExecutionAsync method in your controller?Since your controller has been hit,it makes no sence to modify the value of controller to map your request to another controller

Comment: DynamicRouteValueTransformer  may help for your requirement,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76059981/mapping-area-to-subdomain-asp-net-core-7/76062461#76062461